# Error compiling code due to direction declaration

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am running code from the internet using `iverilog` as follows:

example.v

```
 module example
      (A,B,C,D,E,F,Y);
wire t1, t2, t3, Y;

nand #1 G1 (t1,A,B);
and  #2 G2 (t2,C,~B,D);
nor  #1 G3 (t3,E,F);
nand #1 G4 (Y,t1,t2,t3);
endmodule
```

and example-test.v

```
 module testbench;
 reg A,B,C,D,E,F; wire Y;
 example DUT(A,B,C,D,E,F,Y);

 initial
 begin
  $monitor ($time," A=%b, B=%b, C=%b, D=%b, E=%b, F=%b, Y=%b", A,B,C,D,E,F,Y);
  #5 A=1; B=0; C=0; D=1; E=0; F=0;
  #5 A=0; B=0; C=1; D=1; E=0; F=0;
  #5 A=1; C=0; D=1; 
  #5 F=1;
  #5 $finish;
  end
 endmodule
```

I compile it using the following command

```
 iverilog -o mysim example.v example-test.v
```

and get the following errors:

```
 example.v:1: error: Port A (1) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port B (2) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port C (3) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port D (4) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port E (5) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port F (6) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:1: error: Port Y (7) of module example has no direction declaration.
 example.v:2: error: signal A in module testbench.DUT is not a port.
 example.v:2:      : Are you missing an input/output/inout declaration?
 example.v:2: error: signal B in module testbench.DUT is not a port.
 example.v:2:      : Are you missing an input/output/inout declaration?
```

Is the entire Verilog syntax in `example.v` code incorrect/obsolete?
Why I am getting compilation errors?

The example is taken from youtube nptel
[verilog tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uw25PU5B3k&list=PLRsFfXmDi9IYCNlvNjrsD8bLMmNE0UxBH&index=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is telling you that you need to declare all the module ports using a direction keyword, such as `input` and `output`, in module `example`.  This fixes the errors:

```
module example
      (A,B,C,D,E,F,Y);
      input A,B,C,D,E,F;
      output Y;
wire t1, t2, t3;

nand #1 G1 (t1,A,B);
and  #2 G2 (t2,C,~B,D);
nor  #1 G3 (t3,E,F);
nand #1 G4 (Y,t1,t2,t3);
endmodule
```

About 28 minutes into the video, the `example` code is correct because it uses `input` and `output`.  The code you copied shows up later in the video, and it is incorrect.

Note that there is no need to also declare `Y` as a `wire`.

---

A more concise way which avoids duplicating the port names is as follows:

```
module example (
    input A,B,C,D,E,F,
    output Y
);
wire t1, t2, t3;

nand #1 G1 (t1,A,B);
and  #2 G2 (t2,C,~B,D);
nor  #1 G3 (t3,E,F);
nand #1 G4 (Y,t1,t2,t3);
endmodule
```